# Bus Error on Linux's microcomp used by gtk

Tags: c, linux, gtk, raspbian

I am running this code on Raspbian machine:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
GtkAdjustment *slider_frequency;
GtkAdjustment *slider_duty_cycle;
//GtkWidget *scale1 (GtkOrientation Horizontal, gdouble 0, gdouble 200, gdouble 1);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//service.gnome3.at-spi2-core.enable = true;    
   //NO_AT_BRIDGE ="1"; 
   int pin;
   /*for(pin=0;pin<8;++pin){
      pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(pin,LOW);
   }*/
   // wiringPiSetup();
    wiringPiSetupGpio();
    pinMode(18,PWM_OUTPUT);
    pwmSetMode(PWM_MODE_MS);
    pwmSetClock(4);
    pwmSetRange (200) ;
  //pwmWrite (18, 30);
    //scale1->gtk_scale_set_value_pos();
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "window_main.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

void on_slider_frequency_value_changed(slider_frequency){
    //gtk_main_quit();
    int value;
    value = gtk_adjustment_get_value(slider_frequency);
    //printf("%d\n",value);
    pwmSetClock(value);
}
void on_slider_duty_cycle_value_changed(slider_duty_cycle){
    //gtk_main_quit();
    int value;
    value = gtk_adjustment_get_value(slider_duty_cycle);
    //printf("%d\n",value);
   // pwm_Write(18, value);
    pwmWrite (18, value);
}
```

Interface was designed in Glade. The code is using side lib named wiringPi and I execute it all by:

```
sudo gcc -o gladewin pw.c -lwiringPi -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -export-dynamic 
sudo chmod 777 gladewin
./gladewin
```

and some errors occur. This is output which says that something goes wrong:

```
pw.c: In function ‘on_slider_frequency_value_changed’:
pw.c:54:38: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_adjustment_get_value’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
     value = gtk_adjustment_get_value(slider_frequency);
                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:38:0,
                 from pw.c:1:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkadjustment.h:96:12: note: expected ‘struct GtkAdjustment *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 gdouble    gtk_adjustment_get_value             (GtkAdjustment   *adjustment);
            ^
pw.c: In function ‘on_slider_duty_cycle_value_changed’:
pw.c:61:38: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_adjustment_get_value’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
     value = gtk_adjustment_get_value(slider_duty_cycle);
                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:38:0,
                 from pw.c:1:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkadjustment.h:96:12: note: expected ‘struct GtkAdjustment *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 gdouble    gtk_adjustment_get_value             (GtkAdjustment   *adjustment);
```

I do not understand honeslty how else can I proccess signals if not by declaring a pointers named exactly like in glade program and putting them into slots.

But what is much worse sometimes (statistically 1 to 5 maybe) I am getting

```
bus error
```

or

```
warning ** error retrieving accessibility bus address 
org.freedesktop.dbus.error.serviceunknown
```

or

```
WARNING: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply.
```

And when it happens my microcomp crushes and stops replying to anything but powerring off manually. 
Many sources ([this](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/16327) for instance) tell that in this case one should run in terminal

```
export NO_AT_BRIDGE = 1
```

but nothing helps. So I though that maybe problem is in my code..?
How can one avoid this message and can it be caused by my code?

**UPDATE ONE**

Thanks to Barmar, now I know that shell command should be without spaces
and it must be

```
export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```

but nevertheless it does not help, after ./gladewin I am getting:

```
(gladewin:1324): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to parse /home/pi/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini: input/output error
Bus error
```

**UPDATE TWO**

It all cannot in fixing bus error.. Now I am executing my program after compilation this way:

```
export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
./gladewin
```

and sometimes (not all the time) I am getting this:

```
(gladewin:1319): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to parse /home/pi/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini: Input/output error
(gladewin:1319): Gtk-CRITICAL **: _gtk_css_section_to_string: assertion 'section !=NULL' failed 
(gladewin:1319): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: (null): Failed to import: Error opening file: Input/output error
line 3: 1319 Bus error
```

**OUTPUT OF /home/pi/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini**

```
[Settings]
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false
```

Comment: Your shell syntax is wrong, it should be `export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1`. You can't have spaces around `=` in shell variable assignments.

Comment: You're missing the type specifictions for the parameters `slider_frequency` and `slider_duty_cycle`.

Comment: While it may work, it is considered bad style to drop paramters from the interface if it is under your control. The most callback functions in GTK have more than one parameter. Assuming that your slider is a gtk_scale, the signal handler schould have 2 parameters: `void user_function (GtkRange *range, gpointer  user_data)`

Comment: `gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = flase` There is a typo `flase` -> `false`

Comment: You modified the content of settings.ini in your question. Did it change something of your "Failed to parse..." message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the type declarations for the parameters to your functions, so they're defaulting to `int`.

```
void on_slider_frequency_value_changed(GtkAdjustment *slider_frequency){
    //gtk_main_quit();
    int value;
    value = gtk_adjustment_get_value(slider_frequency);
    //printf("%d\n",value);
    pwmSetClock(value);
}
void on_slider_duty_cycle_value_changed(GtkAdjustment *slider_duty_cycle){
    //gtk_main_quit();
    int value;
    value = gtk_adjustment_get_value(slider_duty_cycle);
    //printf("%d\n",value);
   // pwm_Write(18, value);
    pwmWrite (18, value);
}
```

Comment: This may fix it. Passing the wrong datatype causes undefined behavior, it could be the reason.

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with your `settings.ini` file. I doubt that's related to the program.

Comment: What do you think, what should I do to hadle this?

Comment: I have no idea, I don't know anything about GTK. Does that file even exist?